# Cannot import deepfool module?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am trying to import deepfool 
from this 
https://github.com/LTS4/DeepFool/blob/master/Python/test_deepfool.py.

I am getting error
this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deepfool'
```

from

Comment: Can you please specify the error?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deepfool'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how it works. As I understand you want to download the code. Than you should use `git clone https://github.com/LTS4/DeepFool.git`.

You should use `import <module_name>` in the code. If you want to download this repository, just press the download button or clone it.